# Error: Status 404 trying to push repository busybox

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I tried to push signed images from a machine (A) to a registry on another machine (B).

> docker tag busybox:latest ubuntu:5005/busybox:latest
>
> docker push ubuntu:5005/busybox:latest

The push refers to a repository [ubuntu:5005/busybox] .... Error: Status 404 trying to push repository busybox ... .

> telnet ubuntu 5005

Trying 127.0.1.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Are there any extra settings in order to push signed images on a diff machine. Or just to push without signing? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming you're running a `registry:2` container on machine B - can you share your `docker ps` from that machine?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replay. I have just another registry running there.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't reach this, make sure your ports are properly exposed on the machine and that your networking resolves "ubuntu" to your newest machine correctly.

It's probable Machine A has no rule allowing `ubuntu` to resolve to `<machine B>`.

Make sure you `docker login` as well once you verify this, too.

Comment: Please elaborate "It's probable Machine A has no rule allowing ubuntu to resolve to <machine B>." I still cannot push from a machine to anothers registry. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This docs helped me to solve the problem.

> 1. https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/.
> 2. https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate.
> 3. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04.